# postgres sql error when write special symbol

Tags: postgresql

I got the error when i try to write these two words into postgresql

MetroÂ 
Logic’s

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
```

Comment: what's the respective insert / copy command? what's your client encoding?

Comment: From which charset are the special (non ASCII) letters you are trying to insert?
Generaly setting your client encoding to that charset should be enough

Comment: `SELECT current_setting('client_encoding');` and show the output of psql `\l+` for the database of interest.'

Answer (score 1):

Your encoding of the input is not UTF-8. I can reproduce this behavior if I for instance insert a ISO-8859-1 file in linux with psql.
You should change the input encoding.